# Retrieving image from Microsoft Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

Here is my code to save and retrieve, the retrieve not working.

```
Private Sub btnsave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click
    Dim str As New MemoryStream
    Pic.Image.Save(str, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    Dim buffer(CInt(str.Length - 1)) As Byte
    str.Position = 0
    str.Read(buffer, 0, CInt(str.Length))
    Try
        Dim d As New DAL
        If printchck.Checked = True Then
            d.Dataedit(String.Format("insert into labdetails ( labnme,labspecial,labadress,labphone,labtime,lablogo,labprint)values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}',{6})", txtlabname.Text, txtspeciality.Text, txtadress.Text, txtphone.Text, txttime.Text, buffer, "Yes"))
        Else
            d.Dataedit(String.Format("insert into labdetails ( labnme,labspecial,labadress,labphone,labtime,lablogo,labprint)values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}',{6})", txtlabname.Text, txtspeciality.Text, txtadress.Text, txtphone.Text, txttime.Text, buffer, "No"))

        End If
        MessageBox.Show("تم الحفظ")  ' saved
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Sub retriveimage()
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DAL().selectdatatable("select lablogo from labdetails")

    Dim img_buffer() As Byte = dt.Rows(0).Item("lablogo")

    Dim img_stream As New MemoryStream(img_buffer)
    img_stream.Write(img_buffer, 0, img_buffer.Length)
    '  Pic.Image = Image.FromStream(img_stream)


    Pic.Image = Image.FromStream(img_stream)  ' error here, Parameter is not valid
    Pic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    img_stream.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: When you say "not working", what do you mean? Is there an exception or error message?

Comment: Also you posted code of `Sub retriveimage()`, but it's not clear where you are calling it from. And what is the code above it, starting with `Dim str As New MemoryStream`? Looks like code that should be in a function but it's not showing.

Comment: the first code to save the image to database, the  sub retriving code not working(Parameter is not valid.) and i am calling this code from  the form load event

Comment: Is your pasted code correct? It looks like you have a `Sub` inside another `Sub`, which is not allowed. Can you post more of the code, so we can see the form load event?

Comment: @MakkyMohamad is there an error message ?

Comment: yes ,Parameter is not valid

Comment: @MakkyMohamad you have to tell us which specific line it's happening on.  You may have to [step through the program till it happens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx).  Also when you determine that, please add the error message and the line it's happening on to the question, this will help get a speedy solution!

Comment: Pic.Image = Image.FromStream(img_stream)

Comment: can you confirm on your back end that the image was saved successfully?  Also, according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx), You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.

Comment: You have an SQL injection problem with the DAL code you wrote.  Always, always, always use parameters.  Looks like you are passing your buffer as a string, by the way, when you go to save.

Comment: Why are you doing `img_stream.Write` after getting the stream? And where is `Pic` being declared?